# Should I use NSNotificationCenter to trigger a app refresh?

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

### Background:

I currently have a NSTimer running in my AppDel class (I also have a method to calculate the amount of time my app spends in the background and adds it to the total, in case anyone brings this up).

The timer is checked at different intervals to see if it has reached 12 hours, at 12 hours the app needs to refresh its data from the server.

When this occurs, I need to display a UIAlert which when its button is pressed:
•   Pops off view controllers to the first view controller.

This “refresh” should only be able to occur on 3 (specific)view controllers  out of 7 within my app.

### The Question(s):

Is NSNotifcationCenter sufficient for my requirements?

Where I would add an observer only to the view controllers I want this to occur on?

Is there a better approach I should be taking?

Comment: You can do this by local notifications and also more simple approach like custom delegate methods can also help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya you can implement the NSNotifcationCenter approach but best alternative is to use custom delegate approach .By this way your app will work according to apple guidelines and memory utilisation of app is also less.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSNotificationCenter` is a good approach when you need to send information about some event (for example need of refreshing app) and you want to make as few changes as possible, without redesign all app architecture. I recommend you https://github.com/AllinMobile/AIMObservers because is created to facilitate the work with `NSNotificationCenter` and `NSNotification`.